# visual force remote no serializer

Tags: javascript, extjs, apex-code, visualforce, serialization

I am using sencha and salesforce to build a mobile SDK. My app was working just fine for my part where I was able to query object from salesforce as well as insert. But after adding my co-worker's code into my project i get an error in the javascript console in my browser and I can longer naviaget to my page but only to his, but then when I go to his pages I can;t query any object. If I add my code to my co-worker it works just fine. Am i forgetting to configure something? The error is below I open it up so we can see the stack.

```
Visualforce Remoting Exception: No serializer found for class core.filemanager.FileBlobValue
VFRemote.js:114
$VFRM.Util.errorVFRemote.js:114
(anonymous function)VFRemote.js:129
a.Event.fireVFRemote.js:48
a.Observable.fireEventVFRemote.js:43
_Visualforce.Direct._Visualforce.extend.onProviderDataVFRemote.js:83
a.Event.fireVFRemote.js:48
a.Observable.fireEventVFRemote.js:43
_Visualforce.direct.RemotingProvider._Visualforce.extend.onDataVFRemote.js:91
_Visualforce.extend.handleResponseVFRemote.js:72
aVFRemote.js:35
(anonymous function)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think from the error message provided that you are trying to retrieve binary data (FileBlobValue) with the VF Remote call. It says it cannot serialize the binary data.

FileBlobValue might not be a literal variable that you have in your code so try to consider all the data you are retrieving and determine if any of it contains a blob or binary then remove the suspect fields from the selection.

If you are manually consciously trying to return a blob, encode it to base64.